# Add data to localStorage and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following:

```
  <form onsubmit={ addToLocalStorage }>
  </form>

  this.items = []

  addToLocalStorage(e) {
    var input = e.target[0]
    var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos') || '[]')
    var savedItems = this.items.push(input.value)
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(savedItems))
    console.log(todos)
  }
```

But the outputs only shows:

```
1
2
```

and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
```

Also outputs `1`,`2` but color black in the console (so I think as strings?).

Comment: What's in `localStorage` in the `todos` key when you pull it out ?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(saveItems)) — "savedItems"

Comment: @Omri Aharon Sorry, a typo. I get the same result, though.

Comment: @Max Zuber I get the same: `1` `2` but in strings I think (black color in the console).

Comment: There is a strange code anyway. What are you trying to do? Is this.items dublicates todos?

Comment: the get data from localStorage `todos` isn't really interfering with the resulting ``todos``

Comment: It so strange, but if you know what you want, try this.items.push(input.value); localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(this.items));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.push()` returns the new array length.

```
var a = [].push("a");
a = a.push("b");
```

a is now equal to 2 and that array is gone.

Here's what you want:

```
this.items.push(value);
localStorage["someKey"] = JSON.stringify(this.items);

...

var loadedArray = JSON.parse(localStorage["someKey"]);
```

Comment: No, .push() returns new array length, so console.log() outputs 1 and 2.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall Hey, I think it worked. Why not use `setItem` and `getItem`?

Comment: @Stefan Kendall Weird, but the `localStorage` is reset when I refresh the page?

Comment: @MaxZuber fixed. Feel free to edit such absolutely correct things in the future once you get edit privileges.

Comment: @alexchenco What are you trying to save exactly and in what browser? There's a size limit to storage and different things store differently in different browsers. Strings tend to work across the board to my knowledge. 

I use the json syntax just because I find it a bit cleaner and I don't need to remember the method names. I treat localStorage like a json object and the syntax matches.